# Perform DELETE request to Github API in PHP

Tags: php, github-api

I am working on a project in which I allow a user to sign in using gitHub.then displaying them the users that they are currently following along with the unfollow button. The only thing remaining is the unfollow part. I searched in Github and found the following request:

```
DELETE /user/following/:username
```

Now I don't know how to use this in PHP, please help me with this part.

The second thing is when the user reloads the page, the page fills with so many errors I don't know how to get rid of them.

Comment: You'll want to use PHP's curl functions (or something like Guzzle). Github also offers a variety of PHP SDKs for working with their API at https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/.

Comment: What is the code you use for other requests, such as GET, POST and PUT?

In regards to the many errors you mentioned in the last sentence; this might not be related to this question, so it may be more appropriate to dedicate a new question to it. Please also include the error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cURL with its `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to perform a DELETE request. The result would look a bit like the following (untested!) code:

```
$curl = curl_init($apiUrl . '/user/following/:username');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```